# Что такое packager java и как его написать?

Tags: java

Требуется написать packager, который запускает сериализацию в отдельном треде. Помогите потять, что это вообще?

Comment: сериализацию чего?

Comment: сариализацию объекта. Акцент на "новый тред" и "packager"